# Remove Carriage Return from the final print statement

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re 
import sys 

def isValid(s):
    pattern_= re.compile("[12][\d]{12}$")
    return pattern_.match(s) 


loop = int(input ()) 

output=[]
for _ in range(0, loop):
    ele = int(input())
    output.append(ele)

entries = ''
for x in output :
    entries += str(x)+ ''

print (output ) #['0123456789012']
print (entries ) #0123456789012
print(type(entries )) #str
print(type(output )) #list


# Driver Code 
for _ in range(loop):
    for x in entries:
        if (isValid(x)):
            sys.stdout.write ("Valid Number")
            break      
        else :
            sys.stdout.write ("Invalid Number")
            break
```

Phones Numbers starts with the digit 1 or 2 followed by exactly 12 digits i.e Phones Numbers comprises of 13 digits.

For each Phone Number, print "Valid" or "Invalid" in a new line.
The list is taking wrong input

The output generated is,

```
2
0123456789012
1123456789012
[123456789012, 1123456789012]
123456789012 1123456789012
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
Invalid NumberInvalid Number
[Program finished]
```

Also, I have searched on stack before posting. This looked different issue. If anything matches the error on stack please redirect me there.

```
2
1123456789012
0123456778901
Valid Number
Invalid Number
[Program finished]
```

This is what it should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import re

def isValid(s):
    pattern_= re.compile(r'[1|2][0-9]{12}$')
    return pattern_.match(s)

loop = int(input())

output = []
for _ in range(0, loop):
    output.append(input())

entries = ''
for x in output :
    entries += x + ''

print (output )  # ['0123456789012']
print (entries )  # 0123456789012
print(type(entries ))  # str
print(type(output ))  # list

# Driver Code
for val in output:
    if isValid(val):
        sys.stdout.write('Valid Number')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('Invalid Number')
```

produces

```
1
1234567891234
['1234567891234']
1234567891234
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
Valid Number
[Program finished]
```

print always returns carriage.
Whereas sys.stdout.write doesn't.
The challenge was resolved hence.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def isValid(s):
    pattern_= re.compile(r'[1|2][0-9]{12}$')
    return pattern_.match(s)

loop = int(input())
# no of times loops to run

output = []
for _ in range(0, loop):
    output.append(input())

entries = ''
for x in output :
    entries += x + ''

result = []
# Driver Code
for val in output:
    if isValid(val):
        result.append('Valid Number')
    else:
        result.append ('Invalid Number')

for i in range(len(result )-1):
    print(result[i])
   
print(result[-1], end = " ")
```

This should work too.
`print` first converts the object to a string (if it is not already a string). It will also put a space before the object if it is not the start of a line and a newline character at the end.

When using `stdout`, you need to convert the object to a string yourself (by calling "str", for example) and there is no newline character.

May I also suggest to rephrase your question as it's not a logic issue but a syntax issue.

Comment:
Checked with single and multiple inputs.
Works.

Comment: But it misses on carriage return from first print statement

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below regex

```
def is_valid(s):
    pattern_= re.compile(r'[1|2][0-9]{12}$')
    return pattern_.match(s)
```

I am not sure, why you are appending the numbers to the entities variable. I have changed the code a bit and the regex is working fine.

```
def is_valid(s):
    pattern_= re.compile(r'[1|2][0-9]{12}$')
    return pattern_.match(s)

loop = int(input())

output = []
for _ in range(0, loop):
    output.append(input())

entries = ''
for x in output :
    entries += x + ''

print (output )  # ['0123456789012']
print (entries )  # 0123456789012
print(type(entries ))  # str
print(type(output ))  # list

# Driver Code
for val in output:
    if isValid(val):
        print('Valid Number')
    else:
        print('Invalid Number')
```

Input:

```
5
1234567891234
1893456879354
2897347838389
0253478642678
6249842352985
```

Output:

```
['1234567891234', '1893456879354', '2897347838389', '0253478642678', '6249842352985']
12345678912341893456879354289734783838902534786426786249842352985
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
Valid Number
Valid Number
Valid Number
Invalid Number
Invalid Number
```

Comment: 2
1123456789012
0123456789012
Valid
Invalid

[Program finished] The challenge is to remove space before [Program finished]

Comment: @Subham I didn't quite understand the removal of space, but I have updated the regex pattern. Please check if that solves your problem

Comment: The output is correct based on the regex. But the blank space is not allowed after last output.